# How to Profiler unit test in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, profiling

Can I use VS 2010 Profiler to profile unit test (MSTest)? If yes, how?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you bring up the "Test View" window you can right click on the test you want to profile and choose "Create Performance Session..."

Comment: I get `PRF0023:` Unable to attach to QTAgent process

Comment: Is this only in VS Ultimate?  I have Pro and I don't see it.  It's not explicitly listed here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx