# How to Profile Unit Tests of MsTest in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, profiling, mstest

I've got integration tests which I launch from Visual Studio 2008 Development Edition (they are executed as MSTest unit-tests, even though they are actually integration tests).  I would like to do some profiling while the tests are being carried out.

In my case, I have an MSTest "ordered" test I'm running.  I'd like to collect sampling data while each of the ordered tests is executed.

How do I do this?

p.s. Perhaps I can accomplish this from the command line, if I manually launch mstest from a command prompt, while trying to follow [command line directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/profiler/vs2010-attaching-the-profiler-to-a-managed-application).  Unfortunately, when I try to launch VsPerfCLREnv from the Visual Studio command prompt, it is "file not found."  What the heck?

Comment: I would not do this; a bottleneck for your tests might not be a bottleneck for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Ordered Tests don't have the 'Create Performance Session' option available:
[image: Ordered Tests]

If you had a simple unit test you would be able to create a performance session.

To use command-line profiling you can navigate to \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools where you will see vsperfclrenv.cmd and other tools mentioned on the profiler blog.

Answer (score 2):

I just got profiling working in VS2008. In case it helps anyone, here is how I got it to work:

1. Ensure you are in `Debug` configuration mode
2. Click `Analyse > Launch Performance Wizard`
3. Select `Profile a dynamic link library`
4. Enter the following:

   - Dll path: The dll you want to instrument, located in the bin\Debug of your unit test project
   - Executable path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe`
   - Start Option Arguments:  `/testmetadata:TestList.vsmdi /runconfig:TestRunConfig1.testrunconfig`

     - Adjust this based on the name of your vsmdi and testrunconfig files.
   - Working directory: Your solution root path
5. Choose `Instrumentatation`. I haven't tried Sampling, so I cannot comment on that.
6. Run the new performance project

Using this approach I identified the bottleneck in my code, and the unit tests are now 15x faster, and the users are seeing a 10x speed improvement.

Comment: Do you know if this is expected to work on VS2010? I've tried following the steps (with the updated path to the 10.0 MSTest.exe), and I keep getting the error "`Could not load file or assembly 'VSPerfControl.Interop, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`". Also, in step 4, do you choose the Dll for the test project (e.g. Foo.Test.dll) or the project itself (e.g. Foo.dll)?

Comment: @CalebBell: In VS2010 you can do it much easier. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145536/how-to-profiler-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2010).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in using multiple unit tests (and possibly the entire unit test suite) as the body of work for profiling. Do you know if that is possible?  Or even a good idea?  Maybe I should open a new question, because I haven't seen any related ones. Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: @CalebBell: I'm not sure if its possible, I think a new question is in order for VS2010. The dll you choose is the one you want profiled. It will load the test based on the vsmdi.